# How to round decimals smaller than .5 to the following number in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having this situation where a I have a large database with +1000 products.

Some of them have prices like 12.3, 20.7, 55.1 for example.

```
| Name     | Price          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Product 1| 12.3           |
| Product 2| 20.7           |
| Product 3| 55.1           |
```

(and so on)...

What I've tried is `update prices set price = ROUND (price, 0.1)`.
The output for this will be:

```
| Name     | Price          |
| -------- | -------------- | (after updated)
| Product 1| 12.3           | 12.0
| Product 2| 20.7           | 21.0
| Product 3| 55.1           | 55.0
```

the prices with decimals < .5 will remain the same, and I'm out of ideas.

I'll appreciate any help.

Note I need to update all rows,Ii'm trying to learn about `CEILING()` but only shows how to use it with `SELECT`, any idea on how to perform an `UPDATE CEILING` or something?

Comment: If you want to round up you would typically use [`CEILING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). So perhaps something like `SELECT CEILING(price)`, although you've only given an example of the output you don't want, it would be useful to see the output you do want

Comment: Add some examples of data for the situation that this question is about.

Comment: The second parameter to [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should be an integer.

Comment: You either want `FLOOR` (always round down), `CEILING` (always round up) or `ROUND` (round to nearest integer away from zero). Which you want, we don't know.

Comment: If you are just trying to round to the nearest whole unit you can use Round(price, 0) to indicate you don't want any decimal places.

Comment: @GarethD Exactly, i've tested `CEILING()` and it worked, but as you said that's only a `SELECT`, when i actually need to update the whole database, having prices with decimals away from .5 can be rounded without any problems `10.6 ===>11.0`, but prices under .5 stays the same, for example `9.3====>9.0`, this is the problem for me, maybe trying to get all those prices to reach .5 and then performing a `ROUND()` could be the answer.

Comment: @Larnu `CEILING` working fine but only with `SELECT`, how can i use it on a for example `UPDATE prices set price = CEILING`?

Comment: `UPDATE prices set price = CEILING`? Think about that statement for a second, and you'll working out why it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I can tell you the function call as shown makes no sense.

The second argument to [the `ROUND()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the number of decimal places, not the size of the value you wish to round to. Additionally, the function only accepts integral types for that argument. Therefore, if you pass the value `0.1` to the function what will happen is the value is first **cast to an integer**, and the result of casting `0.1` to an integer is `0`.

We see then, that calling `ROUND(price, 0.1)` is the same as calling `ROUND(price, 0)`.

If you want to round to the nearest `0.1`, that's one decimal place and the correct value for the `ROUND()` function is `1`.

```
ROUND(price, 1)
```

Compare results here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7878c275f0f9ea86f07770e107bc1274

Note the trailing 0's remain, because the fundamental type of the value is unchanged. If you also want to remove the trailing 0`s, then you're really moving into the realm of strings, and for that you should wait and the client code, application, or reporting tool handle the conversion.

Comment: Hi, take a look on the example website you showing, the product 1 that has price 12.300, i need it to be 13, idk how to explain myself since i own the store but i'm not familiar with advanced coding, but from what i understand prices with decimals under .5 won't round at all, and maybe my query is wrong but i don't know how to fix this, i want for example 12.1 to be 13.0 or 10.4 to be 11, maybe i'm focusing on the wrong function, something more mathematical like taking decimals under .5 to be at least .6 and then performing a a `ROUND()`?

Comment: @RoyGivenchi In that case, use `CEILING()` instead of `ROUND()`, as indicated in some of the early comments.